# What is difference between custom dialog and activity as dialog means "Theme.Dialog"?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

Here my question is What is real difference between Custom dialog and activity which I made its theme as dialog and is opening as dialog,
I have used both of these, some of small difference which I understand is follows

1. coding remains in other file in activity and in same file in custom dialog(if we haven't created new class file for dialog),
2. Activity stays in activity stack, while dialog not.

Is there any other difference? So Y we need custom dialog in place of activity as dialog and visa versa,

My current problem is when I click on listitem and it opens new activity (as dialog here), and when i press back button and click again on item it "stops unexpectedly", and couldn't understand error, my error is as below

```
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131230777, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.logicbridge.lazyloader.MyOrdersLazyAdapter)]
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1538)
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForTap.run(AbsListView.java:2728)
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-18 12:21:18.945: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is for listview

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_order_list);
        initControls();
        loadList();
    }

    private void initControls() {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Loading...");
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_order_List);

    }

    private void loadList() {
        StaticItems.myorderadapter = new MyOrdersLazyAdapter(MyOrders.this,
                StaticItems.myOrderListArr);
        list.setAdapter(StaticItems.myorderadapter);
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Starts new activity after some process
                ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
                str.add("loadOrdersDetail");
                str.add("2");
                new MyTask(str).execute();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Does this happens because of I have used new activity instead of dialog??

Answer (score 7):

`Dialog` and `Activity` are completely different things. For example, a service or a broadcast receiver can start an `Activity`, but they cannot start a `Dialog`. In general, a `Dialog` belongs to an `Activity` and the `Activity` controls the lifecycle of the `Dialog` (ie: when it is created, shown, dismissed, etc.). *Note: you can have a `Dialog` that doesn't belong to an `Activity`, but this is a special case.*

There are times when you want to show the user something that looks like a `Dialog`, but you need to use an `Activity` for that. A good example is a `Notification`. Sometimes, when the user chooses a `Notification` from the notification bar, you want to show him a `Dialog`. But you can't start a `Dialog` from a `Notification`. Instead, you use an `Activity` that uses the `Theme.Dialog`. The `Activity` behaves like an `Activity`, but to the user **it looks like a `Dialog`** (ie: it doesn't take up the entire screen, it has a transparent background so the user can see the `Activity` underneath it, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The exception occurs when the data list of a adapter is changed in the background thread and asked for update of listview which results in this crash.

Could you post what are you trying to do in MyTask AsyncTask, which may be useful in identifying the reason for the crash.?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am getting data in MyTask AsyncTask, and in other process it is being changed, which I comment and it works.. Thank you.. and Could you help me to find out difference between activity as dialog and custom dialog?(It will be more helpful).